# Sorting index elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write down number of each rows on the first column of my table.
I have several DOM elements with the named class `studentCounter`.

I tried the following:

```
$('.studentCounter').each(function (i) {
    $(this).html(i + 1);
})
```

However it returns the numbers like: 1, 10, 2, 3 .. and so on.

Then I sorted the elements index like this:

```
var studentItems = [];

$('.studentCounter').each(function (i) {
    studentItems.push(i + 1);
})

studentItems.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
```

It returned the same. 
Thank you for reading

Comment: I couldn't get you..... the array is already in sorted format `[1, 2, 3.....]`

Comment: Have you checked the output in browser console? Check the index by consoling in each loop like this: `$('.studentCounter').each(function (i) { console.log( i );
    $(this).html(i+1);
})`

Comment: yes, i have. the same result. numbers like: 1, 10, 2, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want each row numbered. If so see Snippet.
Details are commented in Snippet.

**Note:** As the example is now, if you have more than one `<tbody>` or `<table>` it will continue to number the first column continuously. If that's not desirable behavior, you must change the selector a little. How I couldn't tell you unless you provide more HTML.

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* The selector is:
|| Find the first <td> of every <tr> of every <tbody>
|| each() <td> found under that criterion...
|| ~~(referenced as $(this) on second line)~~
|| ...set it's text content to it's index number (var idx)
|| offset by 1 (+1).
*/
$('tbody tr td:first-of-type').each(function(idx, td) {
  $(this).text(idx + 1);
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you bery much. your code works perfect. but in my case 
i have sevaral tables in my web pages so it replcaces all the data in the table in the first column. Thats why i created a span class `studentCounter` in td so i need only in the span class write down the row counter